# How to change validation error message dynamically in extended (custom) validator class

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I create a custom validator class that may `return` with diffrent cases, so i need to set custom error messages before each one these `return`.

**I created this Validator Class**

```
class UserConfirmationMessageValidator extends Validator
{
   public function canPassTheMessageConfirmation($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator){
        $confirmationKey = $validator->getData()["confirmationKey"];
        $phoneNumber = $validator->getData()["phone"];

        if(!isset($confirmationKey)){

            if(case1){
                // must set custom error message for this case
            }else { 
                // must set custom error message for this case
            }

            return false;

        }else {

            if(case2){

                return true;

            }else{
                // must set custom error message for this case
            }

        }

      // can return with message that define in (AppServiceProvider => boot), if any cases
      return false;

    }
}
```

**This is my AppServiceProvider Class**

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // some other validators

        Validator::extend('canPassTheMessageConfirmation', UserConfirmationMessageValidator::class."@canPassTheMessageConfirmation","you will receive sms. please wait");

    }

}
```

**My Controller where the rules set**

```
public function store(Request $request) // kullanıcı kaydetme
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'area1' => 'unique:vp_users|required|min:8|max:16|canPassTheMessageConfirmation',
        'area2' => 'required|max:255',
        'area2' => 'required|max:255',
        'area4' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'area5' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
        'area6' => 'required|max:1',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors()->first(),400); // Bad Request
    } else {
        $user = $this->create($request->all());
        return response()->json($user, $request->statusCode);
    }

}
```

**Dumped output of validator's error**, `var_dump($validator->errors());`

```
object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)[246]
protected 'messages' => 
array (size=1)
  'area1' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'you will receive sms. please wait' (length=33)
protected 'format' => string ':message' (length=8)
```

When validator fails with this `canPassTheMessageConfirmation` rule, `validator` returns a message : "*you will receive sms. please wait*" that was defined in `AppServiceProvider` `boot` function. I want to change this message in `canPassTheMessageConfirmation` method of `UserConfirmationMessageValidator` class, according to my return cases. If my explanation is not clear. I can share more code as your wish.

Comment: Can you try `Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, [ 'area1' => ['canPassTheMessageConfirmation' => "Your Message"]]);`

Comment: Tried before the `return false`, but didn't work. 
`Validator::make($validator->getData(), $validator->getRules(), [ 'area1' => ['canPassTheMessageConfirmation' => "Your Message"]]);`

Comment: i added dump of `$validator->errors() method`.

Comment: Can you try `Validator::make($validator->getData(), $validator->getRules(), [ 'area1' => ['can_pass_the_message_confirmation' => "Your Message"]]);` camelCase to snake_case. Give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work too. Thank you for your effort. I think i found the solution, maybe it is not the best solution but it works. shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the way to change the error message dynamically in extended `Validator` class and want to share. Maybe someone who is struggling with such customization use my solution and thanks me. I noticed that the validator object has a `fallbackMessages` array that has parameters of custom error messages that set on `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider` class. You can see how i set custom error message on `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider` class above question.

**Example output of validator object**

```
 public 'fallbackMessages' => 
 array (size=6)
 'are_they_friend' => string 'you must be friend to complete this action!' (length=43)
 'are_they_friend_with_all' => string 'all user you sent video must be your friend!' (length=44)
 'is_member_of_group' => string 'you must be the member of this group!' (length=37)
 'is_media_supported' => string 'this media type is not supported' (length=32)
 'can_refresh_media_list' => string 'that is all for now' (length=19)
 'can_pass_the_message_confirmation' => string 'you will receive sms. please wait' (length=33)
```

So i get the `fallbackMessages` and merge with my modified custom message.

```
$validator->setFallBackMessages(array_replace($validator->fallbackMessages,["can_pass_the_message_confirmation" => "My Message"]));
```

**Dumped output of validator's error**, `var_dump($validator->errors());`

```
object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)[246]
protected 'messages' => 
array (size=1)
  'area1' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'My Message' (length=10)
protected 'format' => string ':message' (length=8)
```